# Set up atom linter-python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows-7, anaconda, atom-editor, pyflakes

I am trying to get a Python linter working in the atom editor on Windows 7 but it seems to do nothing.

I have:

1. Installed the latest [atom](https://atom.io/) editor (version 0.194.0) on Windows,
2. Installed [linter](https://atom.io/packages/linter), and
3. Installed [linter-pyflakes](https://atom.io/packages/linter-pyflakes).
4. Set the following in my atom config file as instructed
   in linter-pyflakes' README file.

   "linter-pyflakes":
   pyflakesExecutablePath: "C:\Users\blokeley\Anaconda3\Scripts"

There seems to be no linter activity when I edit a Python file.

I opened an [issue on the linter-pyflakes project](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-pyflakes/issues/7) but it got no response.

Is the path to the executable wrong? How can I check what linter is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [linter-flake8](https://atom.io/packages/linter-flake8) instead.